# Display none to element in foreach if == 0

Tags: php, foreach

I have a `foreach` loop, and in that I have a more information button. I want it so that when x == 0 then the display to that more information button is 'none'

This is the variable that is different in each foreach item.

```
$issuesFixedCount
```

This is the class that needs to be display none if the variable == 0.

```
<a href="<?='version/?version=' . $item->name; ?>" class="moreInfo">Meer
```

My code:

```
<div class="pb-2 mb-3">
    <h1 class="h2">Recente Jira releases</h1>
    <div class="release-items" id="release-items">
        <?php
        foreach ($items as $item):
            $proj = new ProjectService();
            $versionService = new VersionService();

            $version = $proj->getVersion('', $item->name);
            $res = $versionService->getRelatedIssues($version);
            $uns = $versionService->getUnresolvedIssues($version);

            $issuesFixedCount = $res->issuesFixedCount;
            $issuesUnresolvedCount = $uns->issuesUnresolvedCount;
            $roundedIssue = $issuesFixedCount - $issuesUnresolvedCount;

            if ($res->issueFixedCount == 0){
                echo "
                <script>
                    const moreInfoVar = document.querySelector('.moreInfo');
                    const.style.display = 'none';
                </script>";
            }
        ?>

            <div class="item" id="item">
                <h4>Versie: <?= $item->name;  ?></h4>
                <div class="details">
                    <p>Issues in versie: <?= $res->issuesFixedCount; ?> </p>
                    <p>Afgeronde issues: <?= $roundedIssue;?> </p>
                    <p>Nog te verwerken issues: <?= $uns->issuesUnresolvedCount;?> </p>
                    <a href="<?='version/?version=' . $item->name; ?>" class="moreInfo">Meer info</a><br>
                </div>
                <small><?= $item->releaseDate; ?></small>
                <a class="toggle">Toon meer</a>
            </div>
            <?php
        endforeach;?>
        <?php 
        $startAtValueNext = $_GET['startAt']; 
        $startAtNext = $startAtValueNext += 5;

        $startAtValuePrevious = $_GET['startAt']; 
        $startAtPrevious = $startAtValuePrevious -= 5;

        if ($startAtPrevious <= 0){
            $startAtPrevious = 0;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="Next-Previous">
        <a href="<?='?startAt=' . $startAtPrevious; ?>" style="float:left; display:inline;" id="navPrevious"><- Vorige</a>
        <a href="<?='?startAt=' . $startAtNext; ?>" style="float:right;" class="navNext">Volgende -></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the actual problem? You know what an `if` is, yes?

Comment: You want it to be display: none in the CSS style of the element? Or how about making it so PHP never even echoes it...would that be ok too? Or do you need to show it again later using JS? Either way...where are you stuck? As above, what's stopping you writing an `if` statement? Your post doesn't contain a question or even a problem statement..."I need" just specifies a wish. Please explain properly what you actually need help with.

Comment: sorry forgot to tell the problem. when i do the if, only the first item in the foreach list changes.

Comment: Where / when did you do the `if`, and what exactly did you write? We can't tell, just from a description. Please [edit] the code in your question to include your attempt at writing the `if`, then we can see what the issue might be. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot even find **"== 0"** or **"none"** in your code.

Comment: i changed the code. i added the if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to inject JavaScript in this way. Instead, simply modify what is sent to the browser in the first place:

```
  <p>Nog te verwerken issues: <?= $uns->issuesUnresolvedCount;?> </p>
  <a href="<?='version/?version=' . $item->name; ?>" class="moreInfo" <?= ($res->issueFixedCount == 0 ? 'style="display:none;"' : ''); ?>>Meer info</a><br>
</div>
```

P.S. `document.querySelector('.moreInfo')` will only ever select the first element it finds which has that class. It doesn't target the specific element you're outputting on the current row, so that's one reason why that approach doesn't work.